# BackgroundJob.Schedule Throws Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

I am working on a Project and Writing Unit Tests for HttpHandlers.
On Running the test this Line

```
BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => PokeRequestedChat(c.Id, 1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
```

gives an Exception ex=> **{"JobStorage.Current property value has not been initialized. You must set it before using Hangfire Client or Server API."}**
Otherwise Project is Running fine on Server. This Exception only occurs when running the xUnit Test.

I am new to c# and have no idea about hangfire

Comment: How about the documentation: https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/

Comment: you can remove the 'C' tag, as the question does not relate to 'C language'

Comment: it was C# , Type error

Answer (score 0):

You can`t write unit tests BackgroundJob.Schedule method, because you need a host for Hangfire, and hangfire required registration in your app, you can try write integration tests for Hangfire.Or just Tests your PokeRequestedChat method, or write some wrapper over BackgroundJob.Schedule and mock it.

Comment: Solved the issue by just added this line in test project 
JobStorage.Current = new SqlServerStorage("connectionString");

Comment: than that`s no Unit test, it becomes integration

Answer (score 0):

Solved the Issue by adding this line in Test Class

```
JobStorage.Current = new SqlServerStorage("connectionString");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the error by this line of code (it creates a mock object for `JobStorage.Current`):

```
JobStorage.Current = Substitute.For<SqlServerStorage>(@"Server=.\sqlexpress;Database=test;Trusted_Connection=True;");
```

I used `NSubstitute` in this sample but you can use `Moq` or other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Oldquestion, but maybe someone will still need it:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseActivator(new Hangfire.JobActivator());
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseMemoryStorage();
```

This also sets up a test storage. (You will need Hangfire.MemoryStorage Package)

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**.